# Kotlin default implementations from Java

Tags: java, kotlin, interface

I have an interface in Kotlin that I want to have default implementations so that implementing classes will only have to implement a subset of the methods. Example:

```
interface PersonInterface {
    val firstname: String?
        get() = null
    val lastName: String?
        get() =  null

    val phoneNumbers: List<String>?
        get() = null

    val interests: List<List<String>>?
        get() = emptyList()

}
```

This in my understanding would create default implementations for the methods to return `null` or an empty list or whatever I would have as defaults in general.
But if I create the following class in **Java** (which I expected it would compile):

```
public class Employee implements PersonInterface {
}
```

I get:

> Class Employee must either be declared abstract or implement abstract
> method getFirstName in PersonInterface

Is it possible to use default interface implementation defined in Kotlin from Java?

Answer (score 3):

According to documentation (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html):

Starting from JDK 1.8, interfaces in Java can contain default methods. To make all non-abstract members of Kotlin interfaces default for the Java classes implementing them, compile the Kotlin code with the -Xjvm-default=all compiler option

Note: Prior to Kotlin 1.4, to generate default methods, you could use the @JvmDefault annotation on these methods. Compiling with -Xjvm-default=all in 1.4 generally works as if you annotated all non-abstract methods of interfaces with @JvmDefaultand compiled with -Xjvm-default=enable. However, there are cases when their behavior differs. Detailed information about the changes in default methods generation in Kotlin 1.4 is provided in this post on the Kotlin blog.